# How can I optimize my fonts on my WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, fonts, webfonts, pagespeed, typekit

After testing my site speed on GTMetrix, I noticed that my fonts are the ones that are slowing it down.
I use TypeKit and the webfont Averta that I purchased online.

Does someone know how I could possibly reduce the load time of these fonts?

Ps*: I'm a rookie at coding and I used Elementor to build my website and to implement my fonts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just preload those fonts with Autoptimize or WP rocket copy the URLs fo all fonts and past those URL in preload section in autoptimize advance tab.